# Steps to get array of all available music files in iPhone for iPhone Rington maker application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am creating a rington maker application in this first step I need to get the list of all available songs from my iTunes application while clicking the button.How can I do that?

Comment: First thing is that where is stored you all songs..? in document directory from web Server or in application resource folder.. this is totally unclear question. please be more clear with your issue in question.

Comment: Please include some research you have done or some code you have tried. It seems you are asking for code as a solution. We would be happy to help you if you show you tried all possible means and still you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: Nitin Gohel:I need to get all my music files from my iTunes app

Comment: @vivek http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-custom-ios-music-player/ it's useful for you

Answer (score 1):

You can get all file from app. bundle such like

```
NSMutableArray *ArrlistOfSounds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSError *err;
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:&err];
    for (NSString *tString in dirContents) {
        if ([tString hasSuffix:@".wav"] || [tString hasSuffix:@".mp3"]) // you can also add/remove file extension as per your requirement.
        {
            /// here you can get .wav and .mp3 file from you app. bundle and add it to Array (ArrlistOfSounds)

            [ArrlistOfSounds addObject:tString];
        }
    }

NSLog(@"%@", ArrlistOfSounds);
```

Write this above whole code in you `UIButton's`  method;

Comment: Thanks Patel I will add this and let you know